# Sending a message to whatsapp groups through twilio with asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, twilio

I am trying to use whatsapp business api for my application with twilio. I already have read the documentation of whatsapp business api. My question is, can we use twilio to send the messages to different whatsapp group based on id. 
For example, If I have 3 groups such as Students, Professors, Assistants and based on each different group I want to send a specific message such as Hi to Students, Hello to Professors and Hey to Assistants. 
What I know till now that Whatsapp differentiate everything with specific id, for instance, `chat.whatsapp.com/DeUzzel9O13231`

I also have worked with the twilio and whatsapp api where you can send a message from your twilio number to your whatsapp number like below

```
using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;


class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/console
        // DANGER! This is insecure. See http://twil.io/secure
        const string accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        const string authToken = "your_auth_token";

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var message = MessageResource.Create(
            body: "Join Earth's mightiest heroes. Like Kevin Bacon.",
            from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15017122661"),
            to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15558675310")
        );

        Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
    }
}
```

The code above is only for sending a message to a specific number. Can I do the same thing with the groups? If yes, How? Is there any documentation for that?

Thanks.

Comment: You should provide more information. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also explain your problem in detail. In the title you speak about "sending a message to whatsapp groups" but in the answer body you seem to describe an ASP.NET Core Identity scaffolding issue. Whats the actual question here? [Scaffolding Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) is well covered in the docs

Comment: @Tseng I am sorry. I pressed Enter by mistake and the website uploaded the wrong question. I just edit the whole question. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 7):

Doesn't look like a supported feature just yet.

> "**Can I send messages to WhatsApp groups or manage groups?**
>
> Currently, our API does not support messaging with or managing
>   WhatsApp groups. We expect to add support for groups in the future."

**Source**: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/best-practices-and-faqs#frequently-asked-questions-on-whatsapp-integrations

Comment: Does Twilio started supporting this feature now?? I also have a similar requirement.

Comment: No, see the link: https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/best-practices-and-faqs#api

Comment: Looks like WhatsApp are actually removing the API for groups entirely in the business API according to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/groups/

Comment: Working link to the above (tldr; groups messaging is deprecated in whatsapp business api): https://web.archive.org/web/20201027083706/https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/group